# menu find a child of li element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

What I need to add a class on hover to the a tag with a menu below is the menu. Any ideas?

`<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="">Another</a>

<ul>

    <li><a href="">Sub</a></li>`

...

```
$("#nav li ul li a").hover(
    function() {
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('current');

    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('current');      
        //alert();          
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the anchor tag or to the main menu tag? And are you only doing this when hovering over an item on the sub-menu?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#nav a").hover(
    function() { $(this).closest("a").addClass("current"); },
    function() { $(this).closest("a").removeClass("current"); }
);
```

Comment: I need to add the class to the a tag instead of the parent ul?

Comment: which tag? `a` is a tag, `ul` is a tag, `li` is a tag

Comment: updated my answer. `$(this).closests("a")` will crawl up its heirarchy until it finds an `a` tag, which is what I think you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without jQuery by using css psuedo classes. All elements in html gain a psuedo class of :hover when the mouse is over them.

To select them in CSS:

```
#nav li ul li:hover {
    // Your style here.
}
```

Comment: Bearing in mind IE's (6, and *maybe* 7) refusal to apply `:hover` on non-`a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This method is what you need http://api.jquery.com/closest/ god bless jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Might but just quicker to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav a:hover').parents('div > ul > li:hover > a').addClass('current');
});
```